# Theorem: Euclidean space $\langle E;+\mid R\rangle$ is normed if $||x||=\sqrt{(x,x)}$ , $x\in E$.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove this theorem? Maybe Cauchy's inequality needs to be applied here?

Comment: what's your definition of normalized space?

Comment: Vector space $<L;+|R>$ is normalized if there is a map $||x||:L \rightarrow R$ which assigns real number for every $x \in L$. That real number is called norm of the vector and written $||x||$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the function $x\mapsto \sqrt{(x,x)}$ is a norm, that is, positive definite, homogeneous and respects triangular inequality.

The positive definiteness comes from the one of the inner product: $||x||=0$ iff $(x,x)=0$ iff $x=0$;

homogeneity: $||\rho x||=\sqrt{(\rho x,\rho x)}=\sqrt{\rho^2(x,x)}=|\rho|||x||$.

triangular inequality (here we use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality):

$||x+y||^2=( x+y,x+y)=||x||^2 + ||y||^2 + 2(x,y)\leq ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 + 2|(x,y)|\leq$
$\leq ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 + 2||x||||y||=(||x|| + ||y||)^2$